# Unwanted Lines when rendering using GPU and OpenCL (RX 580)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, opencl

I'm new to blender and have been studying and starting with low poly modeling. Recently I changed my GPU from a GTX 960 to an RX 580. I uninstalled the drivers and installed new ones using DDU.

Problem: Rendering using OpenCL produces these unwanted lines. The attached image is a product of CPU + GPU render then the GPU only render, respectively. When I render using only the CPU the results are as expected, no unwanted black vertical lines, using only the GPU adds more lines on the image.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

[image: CPU + GPU Render]

[image: GPU only Render]

Comment: Attach the GPU-only image then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've edited it already.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in version 2.83.

https://developer.blender.org/T77095