# Rendering in Cycles on OpenCL GPU Compute Leads to Artifacts

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, opencl

I've switched my renderer to GPU compute and get pretty terrible artifacting along with garbled denoising data.

I'm asking this here because Cycles rendering seems to be the only OpenCL workload that this happens in. Other workloads, including Luxmark, all work fine.

I'm rendering with OpenCL with a tile size of 256, and I have branched path tracing enabled.

CPU render:

[image: Normal render by CPU]

OpenCL render:

[image: Render with artifacts from GPU Compute]

OpenCL render (Intel denoised):

[image: Post-denoise from seemingly garbled denoise data]

My system is an i5 6400 with a RX 480 8GB.

I'm rendering with Blender 2.83

Comment: In other files i get similar vertical lines as seen in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181368/unwanted-lines-when-rendering-using-gpu-and-opencl-rx-580?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this issue in older Blender versions. This seems to be an issue related to 2.83, especially on RX480/580s for some reason.

https://developer.blender.org/T77095

Answer (score 0):

I am not an openCL GPU user, but this looks to me like a memory issue. If the amount of memory needed to render the scene is just slightly/right at the amount of memory the GPU has, then sometimes artifacts like this will appear.

Try rendering at a lower quality, and look at the amount of memory taken to render the image. If it *is* around the maximum amount of memory for the GPU, then unless you have another GPU with more memory, I would use the CPU.

Otherwise, if not a GPU memory problem, you will have to use the CPU.