# Weird artifacts when GPU rendering amd rx 480 and ryzen 5 3600x blender 2.83

Tags: rendering, gpu

[image: Wierd artifacts when gpu rendering]

I am having really bad artifacts when rendering with GPU. This does not happen when using the CPU. This is also something that might be to do with the new update. I have fully reset pc and made sure all drivers are up to date.

Comment: See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181368/unwanted-lines-when-rendering-using-gpu-and-opencl-rx-580?rq=1

Comment: Also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181435/rendering-in-cycles-on-opencl-gpu-compute-leads-to-artifacts/181441#181441